# Can iter_swap be specialised?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, c++11, containers

If I have a container `std::vector<T*> items`, I can create an `IndirectIterator` which wraps `std::vector<T*>::iterator` and allows iterating over `T`'s rather than `T*`'s.

Can I specialise `iter_swap` for `IndirectIterator` to make standard algorithms (such as `std::sort`) swap items by pointer?

i.e., if I write the following, will it have any effect on standard algorithms?

```
namespace some_namespace
{
    template <typename IterT>
    class IndirectIterator
    {
            IterT m_base;
        public:
            typedef IterT base_iterator;
            typedef /* ... */ reference;

            /* ... */

            reference operator*() const { **m_base; }

            const base_iterator& base() const { return m_base; }
            base_iterator& base() { return m_base; }
    };

    template <typename T>
    void iter_swap(IndirectIterator<T>& a, IndirectIterator<T>& b)
    {
        using std::iter_swap;
        iter_swap(a.base(), b.base());
    }
}
```

The benefit of this specialisation is that it swaps pointers rather than full T instances, so it's faster (potentially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in C++20, the answer is unambiguously "yes, you *can* customize your own ADL `iter_swap`." STL algorithms *should* use it, but aren't required to, and there is implementation divergence in practice.

For customizing a customization point, you should use the "hidden friend idiom":

```
namespace some_namespace {
    template <class IterT>
    class IndirectIterator {
        IterT m_base;
    public:
        /* ... */

        reference operator*() const { return **m_base; }
        const base_iterator& base() const { return m_base; }

        // "It's not a member, it's just a friend" 
        friend void iter_swap(IndirectIterator a, IndirectIterator b) {
            using std::iter_swap;
            iter_swap(a.base(), b.base());
        }
    };
}
```

Subtle change here: your `iter_swap` had been taking its arguments by mutable reference! That wouldn't work, e.g. if it were passed an `IndirectIterator` that was const, or that was an rvalue. Iterator parameters should always be taken by value. Similarly, there's no sense in providing a non-const version of `base()`. Your `base()` is a getter, not a setter; it should be a const member function for the same reason `vector::size()` is a const member function.

Finally, the big caveat here is that you must never customize `iter_swap` to do anything *observably different from* swapping the targets of the iterators. If you do that, then it's undefined behavior — all bets are off — the program could do anything. Formally, this requirement is given in [[iterator.cust.swap](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.cust.swap#4.1.sentence-2)]:

> If the [`iter_swap`] function selected by overload resolution does not exchange the values denoted by *E1* and *E2*, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

I believe your idea of having `iter_swap` swap the "first-level" targets rather than the "second-level" targets is perfectly kosher, as long as you're never going to rely on observing the difference. The standard library is still *allowed* to bypass `iter_swap` and just do `swap(*it, *kt)` if it feels like it; your code must be able to cope with that, or else "the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required." (I.e., you must fully commit to the idea that swapping those first-level targets is tantamount to "exchanging the values of *E1* and *E2*," and thus interchangeable with any other method of exchanging the values. You can't *rely* on your own method getting used.)

[Here is a complete C++20 example on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/qG5ePGx4T) As of February 2023, here's where I see the customized `iter_swap` actually getting used:

| Algorithm | libstdc++ | libc++ | Microsoft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `std::ranges::partition` | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `std::ranges::sort` | No | No | Yes |
| `std::partition` | No | No | No |
| `std::sort` | No | No | No |

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, `iter_swap` is only used in `std::reverse`, and it does not mention any kind of argument-dependent lookup: it always uses `std::iter_swap`. And since you are not allowed to overload functions in the `std` namespace, you're out of luck.

Comment: Checking some headers from libc++ this looks correct, though it's a little disappointing. I guess I can do it with a custom reference class, but I'm not sure it's worth it just to make swap nicer.

Comment: In C++11 (at least), `std::sort` uses `std::iter_swap`. (and I had to specialize/define `std::iter_swap` to make a certain special iterator work with `std::sort`.

Comment: You are still allowed to specialize templates in `std` namespace as long as they are specialized for user-defined arguments.

Comment: Also, the fact that one implementation only uses `std::iter_swap` in one place does not mean that's the only place it's used, ever, nor that that use is completely correct...

Comment: @AnT **and** as long as you keep the same semantics as the non-specialized version.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I specialise `iter_swap` for `IndirectIterator` to make standard
>   algorithms (such as `std::sort`) swap items by pointer?

You can always make your overload/specialization. However your question is whether you can specialize `iter_swap` *inside* the namespace `std`.

I think the answer is unclear from the standard.
I have found that in some cases, I had to define a special `iter_swap` inside `std` so that `std::sort` uses it. In gcc std lib `std::sort` uses the qualified `std::iter_swap`.

This is probably a defect in `std::sort`. 
IMO `std::sort` should call an unqualified `swap_iter`.

> i.e., if I write the following, will it have any effect on standard
>   algorithms?

Not in GCC (at least) because standard algorithms use qualified `std::iter_swap` (bug?)
I don't think the standard is clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to reopen `std` namespace and specialize templates inside `std` as long as you specialize them for user-defined types. In your case you can actually specialize `std::iter_swap` for your purposes, just make sure you are doing it in `std` namespace, not in your own namespace (as in your example). It is not very elegant, but it is allowed.

Comment: You're allowed to specialize _certain class templates_ for your own types, e.g. `std::hash<Mine>`. You're not allowed to specialize other class templates, e.g. `std::vector<Mine>`; and you're _never_ allowed to specialize function templates like `iter_swap` or `make_pair` or `sort` or `min`. In practice you physically can't, anyway, because you don't know their True Names (e.g. how many template parameters they have). You are allowed to _customize_ the behavior of certain operations by overloading/ADL (`swap`, `+`, `<`, `iter_swap`, `strong_order`), but that's not "specializing templates."